# (android) how to make circle loading screen when system connecting to server, and if error show the message

Tags: android

i have code like this

```
private void ATM(){
        //marker
        final MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        final MapWrapperLayout mapWrapperLayout = (MapWrapperLayout)findViewById(R.id.map_relative_layout);
        final GoogleMap maps = mapFragment.getMap();
        maps.clear();

        // MapWrapperLayout initialization
        // 39 - default marker height
        // 20 - offset between the default InfoWindow bottom edge and it's content bottom edge
        mapWrapperLayout.init(maps, getPixelsFromDp(this, 39 + 20));

        // We want to reuse the info window for all the markers,
        // so let's create only one class member instance
        this.infoWindow = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow, null);
        this.infoTitle = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.infoSnippet = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
        this.infoButton = (ImageButton)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.button);

        // Setting custom OnTouchListener which deals with the pressed state
        // so it shows up

        this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(infoButton,
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.klik_untuk_gambar)) {
            @Override
            protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
                // Here we can perform some action triggered after clicking the button
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, marker.getTitle() + "'s button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(marker.getTitle().equals("WC Umum")) {
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url + Gambar).into(imageView);

                    android.app.AlertDialog dialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setView(imageView)
                            .setPositiveButton("close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }).create();

                    dialog.show();
                }
                else{
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StreetViewActivity.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("LatitudeMarker", LatitudeMarker);
                    myIntent.putExtra("LongitudeMarker", LongitudeMarker);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }

            }
        };
        this.infoButton.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);


        maps.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // Setting up the infoWindow with current's marker info
                infoTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                infoSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                infoButtonListener.setMarker(marker);

                LatLng position = marker.getPosition(); //get lating
                LatitudeMarker = String.valueOf(position.latitude); //get only latitude
                LongitudeMarker = String.valueOf(position.longitude); //get only longitude
                Gambar = LatitudeMarker+"_"+LongitudeMarker+".jpeg"; //get image name
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url+Gambar).into(infoButton);
                // We must call this to set the current marker and infoWindow references
                // to the MapWrapperLayout
                mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
                return infoWindow;
            }
        });

        //get data from ATM
        String urlATM = FIXURL+"ATM.php";
        try {
            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(urlATM));
            if(data.length()!=0){
                HashMap<String, String> map;

                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("id_atm", c.getString("id_atm"));
                    map.put("latitude", c.getString("latitude"));
                    map.put("longitude", c.getString("longitude"));
                    map.put("name", c.getString("name"));
                    map.put("email", c.getString("email"));
                    MyArrListATM.add(map);
                    //end add marker

                    maps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .title("ATM"+MyArrListATM.get(i).get("id_atm"))
                            .snippet("24 Jam")
                            .position(new LatLng(
                                    Double.parseDouble(MyArrListATM.get(i).get("latitude")),
                                    Double.parseDouble(MyArrListATM.get(i).get("longitude")))));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //
    }
```

now when i call this function it just stuck at the screen while loading and i don't know the connection to database error or no, so i wan't make a circle loading screen when this function is call and if connection to database error show the message